# Использование credentials: "include" при getInitialProps в NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nextjs

Могу ли я использовать credentials: "include" при fetch в getInitialProps?

```
  const res = await fetch(api, {
    credentials: "include",
  });
  const content = await res.json();

  return { content }
```

Я что-то делаю не так, но куки не отправляются на сервер.
Использую NextJS

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил.
Спарсил куки и отправил их вручную.

```
let cookie = context.req.headers.cookie;
let cookiestring=RegExp("cookie_name"+"[^;]+").exec(cookie);
let token = decodeURIComponent(!!cookiestring ? cookiestring.toString().replace(/^[^=]+./,"") : "");
```

Потом:

```
headers: {
  Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
}
```

Возможно способ не лучший, но рабочий